# modifiy .csproj from AfterBuild target

Tags: msbuild

I have a Afterbuild target in which I add some generated files to a project (.csproj). Now when the build completes Visual Studio says 'the project has been modified outside the environment' and asks whether I want to reload.

Is there to make it auto-reload (without using tools->options or environment->options) from msbuild?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?  Or what approach did you end up taking?

Comment: Does the generated code output have a predictable pattern? Is there a reason you don't add the generated code items to the project outright (ie actually have the items in the Content or Compile ItemGroups?) so it is always referenced?